# How do i dump .schema of SQLite table?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, schema

I'm a noob to android and I am having trouble creating entries and retrieving data from my table.  It was suggested in another post [How to do i resolve IllegalArgumentException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179114/how-to-do-i-resolve-illegalargumentexception) , that i should get a dump of the .schema of the database to see if it is being constructed properly?  How do i do this?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the adb shell, you can type the command

```
sqlite3 /data/data/<your-namespace>/databases/<database-name>
```

There you can see all the tables with the command `.tables`
Schema of each table `pragma table_info(<table-name>)`

This way you can see the tables created in the emulator by your app.

Comment: do i access the adb shell using the cmd window?

Comment: yes. I know how to do it in linux but am not familiar with windows setup.